British Children's Educational Televison show from the 80's / 90's about an alien disguised as a chair
I recently recalled a British educational television show I watched in my childhood where a young boy would talk about human life with some kind of alien creature who appeared to him as a dining room chair. The detail of a specific episode that I can recall is him talking about vacuum cleaners / lawn mowers, and a reference to the boy's father having proposed to give the carpet a go-over with the lawn mower.
Does anyone recall this show and can provide more details?

Honestly, I would just remove the entire part about chat gpt's madness from your answer. It is incredibly poor at identifying story ID questions for anything less obvious than Star Wars or The Godfather

to add to valorum's comment, ChatGPT is not a search engine, and cannot be relied to produce factual information. It gives you a response that seems like it would be a likely response based on its training data. Generally that means it gives you something that looks like it could be the answer, but that is something very different from an actual answer

What little I have seen output and discussed about the same from the LLM tools is that they behave in the way one might expect an abused partner to behave.  They will give you what they suppose you want to hear, if caught in a lie/error they apologise and adjust to keep you happy.  If you don't already know the answer the LLM will not provide it for you.

This is Helping Henry (1988).

Designed as an educational show, it featured a young boy named Stephen explaining how things worked to an alien named N-3 (or "Henry"), who was disguised as a dining-room chair because his superiors believed that static four legged things were clearly a superior species to the 'two legs' who bustled about them.





That theme song brought back some memories, thanks for the answer!

@NeilTarrant - I can only assume that every single person involved with this production was really high.

i'm laughing, thats genius! and blimey, those studios were great !

I've heard of "Four legs good, two legs bad" but this is pushing it!
